# Porque eu não consigo recuperar a quantidade de registro que corresponde ao intervalo das datas?

Tags: php, laravel

```
        $quantidade_week = DB::table('serviceorders')
        ->where('serviceorders.status_serviceorders', '=', 'OPENED')
        ->WhereDate('serviceorders.date_started_serviceorders', '>=', $firstDayOfInterval)
        ->WhereDate('serviceorders.date_started_serviceorders', '<=', $lastDayOfInterval)
        ->get()
        ->count();
        dd($quantidade_week);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que está fazendo `->get()->count();`, para contar não é necessário chamar a função `get` apenas a `count`:

```
$quantidade_week = DB::table('serviceorders')
    ->where('serviceorders.status_serviceorders', '=', 'OPENED')
    ->whereDate('serviceorders.date_started_serviceorders', '>=', $firstDayOfInterval)
    ->whereDate('serviceorders.date_started_serviceorders', '<=', $lastDayOfInterval)
    ->count();

dd($quantidade_week);
```

Comment: Então @Guilherme Constamilam, retirei o ->get, uma função a mais para complicar o processo, no entanto, ainda persiste resultando 0 registros.

Comment: não seria porque o campo date_started_serviceorders esta no formato 2019-03-14 00:00:00 e a variavel do filtro é 03/14/2019 ?

Comment: É bem provavel. Tente passando no mesmo formato, algo como `->whereDate('serviceorders.date_started_serviceorders', '>=', date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $firstDayOfInterval))`. Uma observação importante, o correto é `whereDate` e não `WhereDate`

Comment: UAU! Obrigado @guilherme Costamilam
Resolvido!!!!! Apliquei as duas dicas e funcionou perfeito!

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema marque ela como aceita no botão "v" superior esquerdo da mesma